Doubts about x86 Memory Barrier
I want to know if sfence blocks refreshing storebuffer, lfence blocks processing invalidate queue, and mfence not only refreshes storebuffer but also processes invalidate queue.
I also want to know if lfence can prevent loadstore reordering,Because the loadstore barrier in Java uses lfence.

What JVM uses lfence for memory ordering?  LoadStore reordering is always forbidden on x86.  (Does it make any sense to use the LFENCE instruction on x86/x86_64 processors?).  If a JVM uses lfence, it might be for Spectre mitigation?

See also Why is (or isn't?) SFENCE + LFENCE equivalent to MFENCE? for details on what x86 barriers actually do.  Invalidation queues can be ignored; on x86 at least they don't create any possible memory-reordering effects that aren't explainable without them.  x86's memory model is program order + a store buffer with store-forwarding.  (So other than store-forwarding, the only allowed reordering is StoreLoad)

(sfence can be useful after NT stores, before a plain store, to give it release semantics.  Otherwise no effect.  lfence blocks execution of later instructions until earlier ones complete, draining the ROB (ReOder Buffer).  And maybe having a memory-ordering effect if you were doing any SSE4.1 NT loads from WC memory, e.g. from video RAM, but Intel recommends mfence for that.)

@Peter Cordes So, SFence won't refresh the storebuffer, MFence can, right?

What do you mean "refresh"?  mfence waits for the store buffer to drain before any later loads (or stores) interact with cache / memory, sfence only orders stores against stores (including NT stores).

@Peter Cordes ok,If it is another CPU architecture (containing an invalidate queue), lfence will not handle the invalidate queue, but mfence can, right?

What reordering effects can an invalidation queue create that you'd need to "handle" with anything?  (Including on a hypothetical weakly-ordered ISA that has an execution-barrier instruction that also does LoadLoad + LoadStore ordering.)

@Peter Cordes The Invalidate is not in fact applied, but placed to a special queue, to be executed when convenient.I want to know if lfence and mfence will block the processing of invalidation messages

I know what an invalidation queue is, but why does it matter?  Isn't it just another potential source of LoadLoad reordering, which can happen in plenty of other ways (on non-x86 ISAs that allow LoadLoad reordering)?

@Peter Cordes " Load Memory Barrier (a.k.a. LD, RMB, smp_rmb) is the instruction that tells the processor to apply all the invalidates that are already in the invalidate queue, before executing any loads , Store Memory Barrier (a.k.a. ST, SMB, smp_wmb) is the instruction that tells the processor to apply all the stores that are already in the store buffer, before it applies any that come after this instruction" Is this what I saw online correct?

On ISAs that have a lightweight LoadLoad (+LoadStore) barrier instruction, yeah I think it would have to drain the invalidation queue as well as waiting for earlier loads to complete.  Otherwise it wouldn't properly order loads against earlier loads for e.g. release/acquire sync.  Draining invalidation queues are not the only thing a LoadLoad barrier needs to do, so that just seems like an unnecessary detail to mention.

@Peter Cordes "Store Memory Barrier (a.k.a. ST, SMB, smp_wmb) is the instruction that tells the processor to apply all the stores that are already in the store buffer, before it applies any that come after this instruction"  Does it mean that SFence will wait for the storebuffer?

On a hypothetical weakly-ordered x86, sfence only blocks StoreStore reordering, not LoadStore.  smp_wmb() needs to block both to make it a release fence like atomic_thread_fence(release).  (https://preshing.com/20130922/acquire-and-release-fences/).  On real x86, smp_wmb() only needs to block compile-time reordering with asm("" :::"memory"), no asm instructions needed, because functions like smp_wmb() assume you aren't using NT stores, or if you are that you used sfence after them.

Like I wrote in my answer on Why is (or isn't?) SFENCE + LFENCE equivalent to MFENCE? which I already linked, SFENCE is like a divider on a grocery-store checkout conveyor belt (the store buffer).  Execution of later loads (or other non-memory instructions) doesn't wait for the store buffer to drain.  At least not on Intel. IIRC, AMD gives it stronger semantics.

@Peter Cordes Thank you for your patient reply :)

@Peter Cordes "...... It also ensures that the
contents of the store buffer are always drained to memory in the following situations:
• When an exception or interrupt is generated.
• (P6 and more recent processor families only) When a serializing instruction is executed.
• (Pentium III, and more recent processor families only) When using an SFENCE instruction to order stores.
• (Pentium 4 and more recent processor families only) When using an MFENCE instruction to order stores" ---- intel
Does it mean that SFence will wait for the storebuffer?

SFENCE will wait for the store buffer before later stores, including NT stores, but not necessarily before later loads unless P4 and later have a lot stronger semantics for it than I thought.  What are you quoting from?  I'm curious what actual SFENCE guarantee was new in Pentium 4.  It was part of SSE1 so did exist in PIII before P4.  I think I remember seeing a StoreLoad reordering litmus test like https://preshing.com/20120515/memory-reordering-caught-in-the-act/ where sfence didn't stop that effect the way mfence or lock add byte [rsp], 0 would; you or I could run that experiment.

@Peter Cordes  https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/content-details/782158/intel-64-and-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-s-manual-combined-volumes-1-2a-2b-2c-2d-3a-3b-3c-3d-and-4.html  Index page 3456 "12.10 storebuffer"

@Peter Cordes "The Sfence will cause the CPU to flush its store buffer before applying each subsequent store to its variable’s cache line. The CPU could either simply stall until the store buffer was empty before proceeding, or it could use the store buffer to hold subsequent stores until all of the prior entries in the store buffer had been applied."   The implementation in x86 is the second type, right?

Oh, the parentheticals come before the thing they apply to.  SFENCE was new in PIII (SSE1), MFENCE was new in P4 (SSE2).  If you look at the manual of SFENCE (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sfence), the pseudocode says Wait_On_Following_Stores_Until(preceding_stores_globally_visible); but the description text says It is not ordered with respect to memory loads or the LFENCE instruction.  So the only thing place SFENCE waits is the store buffer itself, not execution of later instructions.  It's not rare for Intel's docs to be phrased in misleading ways like this. :/

And yes, Intel CPUs don't stall while waiting for the store buffer to drain, they just insert a "divider" / "fence" into the store buffer that the commit hardware can't look past when looking for NT stores ready to commit to an LFB.
